# How to reduce size of image display window in opencv?

Tags: c, opencv

I am using opencv to process very large images (some times even more than 2500x2000). When I display such an image using a normal cvNamedWindow it occupies the whole screen and even I am unable to scroll down or sideways to see other parts. Is it possible to reduce the size of image only while displaying?

Note: the size of my images are not constant

platform used : visual studio

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the flag `CV_WINDOW_NORMAL` to alter this behavior. This flag will make the window manually-resizable.

```
cvNamedWindow(yourWindowName, CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
```

Comment: see for yourself http://www.cognotics.com/opencv/docs/1.0/ref/opencvref_highgui.htm

Answer (score -1):

i don't know whether any in-built function is available to do that or not, but i can suggest u to write ur own image processing function for displaying the generated image... which takes only alternate rows and column information for display that wud reduce the image to 1250X1000, so depending on ur need u can take every 3rd row or column if u want the size to be further less... This wud give a hit to the performance as per displaying time as temporary images wud need to be generated but wud give u the desired results.